# Add Item to Array If Not In the Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Each time I click the "Add item" button it repeatedly adds `item` to the `items` array. For example, if I click "Add item" five times the array is:

```
items: [item, item, item, item, item]
```

How can I modify my code to add the first `item` but not add additional `item`s to the array, like so:

```
items: [item]
```

I tried replacing `var i = -1` with `var i = 0` but that never adds `item` to the `items` array.

Here's my view:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add {{item}}</button>
  <p>items: {{items | json}}</p>
</body>
```

...and controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = 'item';
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.addItem = function () {
    for (var i = -1; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.items[i] != $scope.item) {
          $scope.items.push($scope.item);
        }
    }
  };
});
```

Here's my Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OT900pXEcxGgkpJZna2x?p=preview

Comment: Did you try if $scope.items.indexOf($scope.item) != -1 than push item in array?

Comment: Do you only want to `push` one time (on the first time)?

Comment: What is your rationale behind using `$scope.items[i]` when `i` is -1? What is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: @Amit Yes, just one at a time.

Comment: @doldt It was just for troubleshooting. If I set it to 0 (instead of -1) it returned nothing.

Comment: *One at a time* or *one time*? Not the same, and if you only want that any click after the first is ignored, there are much easier ways to do that.
P.S. when you had `i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++` nothing happened since length was 0, and 0<0 is false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Add a simple validation

In `addItem()`, add a simple validation using `indexOf` to check if the item is in the array:

```
$scope.addItem = function () {

    if ($scope.items.indexOf($scope.item) != -1){
      // The item is already in the array, abort!
      return;
    }

    $scope.items.push($scope.item);
}
```

## http://plnkr.co/edit/GKtREKBXUD7J54oxTaDq?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a forked version of your plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gtuUyeYXCIcXGPTqbeuj?p=preview)

It uses [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which is a built-in function to tell whether an array contains an elment or not (it returns -1 when the item is not found):

```
$scope.addItem = function () {
  if($scope.items.indexOf($scope.item) === -1){
      $scope.items.push($scope.item);
  }
};
```

I'm not sure what were you trying to achieve by referencing `$scope.items[-1]`, care to elaborate?